# ColorTranslator.FromHtml / ToHtml Equiv in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

After googling, no solution was found.  I am upgrading an old project of mine to WPF (which I have 0 experience in and am doing this to learn) but can't find an equivalent method to:

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.White)
```

I was using this to store and retrieve colors from XML.  Do any of you know an equivalent method in WPF?

Comment: System.Drawing.ColorTranslator is a class which will be available if you include System.Drawing in your project. may be you are missing a reference to System.Drawing

Comment: Already added it, takes the include statement, but still doesn't recognize the command.  I see nothing about it regarding WPF =(

Comment: add a reference to System.Drawing i am able to view it in my solution.

Comment: Ok...I didn't think it would take an include statement if it didn't have a reference but you guys are right.  Thanks.

Comment: System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color.White);

Comment: @GaidenFocus Did the following answers solved your problem? Would you like to accept one of them?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are using `System.Windows.Media.Color` try using [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, This may solve your problem:

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color.White);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Reference to System.Drawing like below,

[image]

Then go for

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color.White);
```